# Codeigniter: Display data from one table in to a page with ID from another table passed in the URL

Tags: codeigniter

I have two tables in my db one table has column called utility_id which coresponds with cu_id in another table

```
towns            cunits
-------          ----------
town_id          cu_id
town             utility
utility_id
```

Now I'd like to display towns in the cunits $id page.. am getting error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: query
>
> Filename: templates/view_utility.php
>
> Line Number: 26

**My Controller -  Utilities.php**

```
public function details($id) {

     $cudata = $this->utilities_model->getById($id); 
     $data['utility'] = $cudata['utility'];
     $this->load->view('header', $data);
     $this->load->view('sidebar-left', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/view_utility', $data); //cunits details page view
    $this->load->view('sidebar-right', $data);
     $this->load->view('footer', $data);
   }

 }
```

**My Model - Utilities_model.php**

```
   function listTowns($id) {  
$query = $this->db->get_where('towns', array('utility_id' => $id));
//return $query->result();
$results=$query->result_array();


$data['query']=$query->result_array();
}
```

**My View - templates/view_utility.php**

```
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
          <li><?php echo $row['town'] ?></li> 
          <?php endforeach; ?>
```

my url is passes out as

> localhost/my-folder/utilities/details/$id

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't assign any data named by 'query' to the view so you cannot reach it.
Try this:

**Controller - Utilities.php**

```
public function details($id) {
    $data = array();
    $data['towns'] = $this->utilities_model->listTowns($id);
    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view('sidebar-left', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/view_utility', $data);
    $this->load->view('sidebar-right', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer', $data);
}
```

**Model - Utilities_model.php**

```
public function listTowns($id) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('towns', array('utility_id' => $id));

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**View - templates/view_utility.php**

```
<?php foreach($towns as $town): ?>
    <li><?php echo $town['name'] ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can't say much -- big thanx Zaragoli